# Remove folder during maven generate-sources or maven install

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I'm trying delete folder before execute the `generate-sources` or `install`. I'm already doing this during the `clean` with the folders under `src/main/java`, but I wanted to try also in a different moment, just because I'm sure that is impossible to forget to delete some file/folder. How do this?

Comment: When you say - 'I'm already doing this during the clean' do  you mean the clean plugin is deleting the folder in question (in target), or something else?  There are a number of ways to do it.  Find a plugin that deletes things and bind the goal to the phase before generate-sources

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear about which directory your are talking about...furthermore usually directories in `target` are simply handled by maven-clean-plugin which means no manual configuration is needed...

Comment: Now I'm deleting folders and files under src/main/java with maven-clean-plugin.  Rich, the meaning is that this pluging go when I use the maven clean but I want that It go during generate-sources or install. Edit question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example at [Apache Maven Clean Plugin / Delete Additional Files Not Exposed to Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html).

- Adapt the `<configuration>` section given there according to your needs and with:

  ```xml
                      ...
                      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                      ...
  ```
- Add an `<executions>` section like:

  ```xml
      ...
      <plugin>
          ...
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>delete-files</id>
                  <!-- 'initialize' is the phase before 'generate-sources'
                        use 'verify' to execute it before 'install' -->
                  <phase>initialize</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>clean</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
          ...
  ```

The result will be:

> ```xml
> ...
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (delete-files) @ so-51708371 ---
> [INFO] Deleting ...path to workspace...\so-51708371\target
> [INFO] Deleting ...path to workspace...\so-51708371\src\main\java (includes = [**/*.tmp, **/*.log], excludes = [**/important.log, **/another-important.log])
> [INFO]
> ...
> ```